# Galaxy S8+ and Apple Music downloads

Tags: drm, apple-music

I have a new Galaxy S8+ and Apple Music installed, but I don't have an SD card. Where the heck do the songs go when I click the download button in Apple Music? I'm tyring to get my music onto my (Generation 4) iPod. I have an iCloud account but there is no "Music" folder there.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you putting the songs onto your phone or your iPod? How are these two things related?

Comment: I have Apple Music on my phone (Android) and I want to put the songs on my iPod via my PC. I click the download button within Apple Music, but I have no idea where they are stored or how to get them onto my computer. I know you can download them to an SD card, but I don't have one yet.

Comment: No one else has this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apple Music is a streaming music service and can't be downloaded as local files unless you convert the DRM-format songs to MP3 or any other DRM-free format. You can google "Sidify" and the info may help you solve the issue.